# Reattach to a process after ssh disconnect

Tags: ssh, putty, process, session

I logged into the server using Putty/ssh started a process and walked away.  Came back to find the putty session had timedout/terminated/become inactive.  When I log back in the process is still there and running.

Is there anyway I can get connected back to either that session or that process?

Comment: Related: [nohup on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup)

Answer (score 2):

No you can't. But you can use `screen` for that purpose, it creates a virtual terminal where you can run the process you want, then detach from it and reattach whenever you want.

- Create a new screen:

  `screen -S [session_name]`
- Detach from that session

  `<Ctrl> + <A> then <D>`
- Reattach to a session:

  `screen -r [session_name]`

Comment: Screen is also great for doing some terminal magic, for example running multiple terminals on split screen or sharing terminal sessions. It's a must-have in my Linux toolbox.

Comment: Alternatively, the “modern way”: [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Yep, `tmux` seems nice too, but I don't know how to use it. Also `detach` is a program specifically dedicated to detach from and reattach to a terminal a process.

Answer (score 1):

The tremendously useful [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr/) utility does just this. Once installed, simply make a note of the PID of the process you want to regain control of and then run:

```
reptyr PID
```

Its author wrote a [series](https://blog.nelhage.com/2011/01/reptyr-attach-a-running-process-to-a-new-terminal/) of [blog](https://blog.nelhage.com/2011/02/changing-ctty/) [posts](https://blog.nelhage.com/2014/08/new-reptyr-feature-tty-stealing/) explaining some of the finer details.

Runs on Linux and FreeBSD, but the latter does not support the "TTY-stealing" feature invoked via the `-T` option.

Comment: Good news. The support for the `-T` option has been added since version 0.8.0.